# Eclipse maven run configuration using 'run' goal from tomcat7 maven plugin doesn't respect default context path

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm working on a web service locally, built using maven and deploying to tomcat.  I'm using the maven plugin to run locally, using `mvn tomcat:run` as my run configuration.

Right now, my service is being deployed using the default project name as a context path:

`http://localhost:8080/myArtifactId/servletPath`

I would instead like to deploy to remove the context path, and deploy to this url **through configuring the tomcat maven plugin**:

`http://localhost:8080/servletPath`

Per this documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html

I am trying this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Why isn't this working??? -->
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Any ideas on why what I'm trying isn't working, or a different way I can go about this?  As I've stated, I'm trying to do this through the maven plugin.

**Alternatively, does anyone know how to pass this in as an argument to the run configuration?** Maybe passing it in explicitly at the command line will override the default.

**UPDATE:** Running `mvn tomcat7:run` or `mvn clean tomcat7:run` from the command line appears to make this work as intended.  But when I run using a `Maven Build` run configuration in Eclipse, the service is started using the default artifact ID, regardless of what I put in the path variable in my `pom.xml`.

**UPDATE:** This appears to be a problem with the Eclipse Maven plugin.  When I run the command from the command line, everything works as expected but when trying to add an Eclipse/Maven run configuration with a Tomcat7:run goal, the project keeps running using the default artifact id context path.

Comment: That should do the trick. Maybe it sounds silly but do you maybe have the tomcat plugin defined twice in your pom? One with the settings you're showing and the other one with a different path?

Comment: I just did a search on my entire workspace (all files matching `*.*`) for `tomcat7-maven-plugin` and only found one instance in my pom.xml.

Comment: Did you try `mvn clean tomcat7:run`?

Comment: I remember I got the same problem by using Eclipse and I couldn't get the solution. I was thinking it is about Eclipse but maybe it is about tomcat plugin.

Comment: @Bart - that did the trick.  I haven't used maven that much so I'm still getting used to nuances.  Please put that as an answer so I can upvote/accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When experiencing problems with maven they mostly get solved by using the **clean** plugin (`mvn clean`) which cleans out your project's working directory.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/

Comment: Actually, that looks like it works when I run the command line.  But, when I run from the Eclipse run configuration I created using the `Maven Build` template, it is still defaulting to the artifact id context path.

Comment: I gave up on using eclipse with the maven plugin. I never had one project that didn't run into problems. When problems did arise they were mostly temporarily fixed using `Maven -> Update project`.

Comment: That didn't appear to work.  I'll file a bug with the eclipse maven plugin.  In the meantime though I'll probably just install the google terminal plugin and move to starting from the command line instead of through the maven run configuration.