# Maven tomcat plugin does not accept path

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am currently trying to set a path that is different from my artifactId of the maven-project. Unfortunately, my attempts do not work.

I tried setting it by

```
   <build>
      <plugins>
        [...]
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/AWV</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
      <finalName>AWV</finalName>
    </build>
```

but when calling `mvn tomcat7:run-war` none of them works (but the war is corretly named AWV.war).

All documentation I could find (http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/configuration.html, http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-war-mojo.html) says I could do this by setting the path this way.

Alternatively, I tried running tomcat with `mvn tomcat7:run-war -Dmaven.tomcat.path=/AWV` which didn't work either. Additional hints, like executing `clean` before ([Eclipse maven run configuration using 'run' goal from tomcat7 maven plugin doesn't respect default context path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187468/eclipse-maven-run-configuration-using-run-goal-from-tomcat7-maven-plugin-doesn)) did not work either.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

**Edit**: This also happens when using 2.3-SNAPSHOT of the tomcat-maven-plugin.

Comment: What version to tomcat are you using?

Comment: I am using Tomcat7 and the corresponding plugin-version.

Answer (score 2):

After searching for some time, I found out the mistake: in `src/main/webapps/META-INF/context.xml` there was the text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/awv-seite"/>
```

I have no clue how this file got there, probably eclipse or NetBeans created it. This prevented all my other tries from beeing successfull, after setting the path there, everything works.